# 1 document with updates vs Many smaller and inserting

Tags: mongodb

I need to develop a data set for users which stores their favourite items - maybe 5% of users will have favourites, and for those perhaps 5-10 favourites on average, with a max of 50.  Almost every user will have a "get favourites" call happen, regardless of if they have them, but will probably add infrequently

My assumption is: There will probably be 100x more "get favourites" than "add/post favourite".

Would it be better to have this structure in mongo, which may slow inserts (since it needs to update 1 document per user), but could be faster to retrieve all.

```
{
  _id : 123456,  (the user id)
  favourites : [
     { item_id : 43563, created_date : ... },
     { item_id : 31232, created_date : ... },
     { item_id : 23472, created_date : ... }
  ]
}
```

Or 1 document per favourite

```
{
  _id: ...,
  user_id : 123456,
  item_id : 43563,
  created_date:...
}
{
  _id: ...,
  user_id : 123456,
  item_id : 31232,
  created_date:...
}
{
  _id: ...,
  user_id : 123456,
  item_id : 23472,
  created_date:...
}
```

The second structure is probably more flexible for future requirements change, but I assume the first structure would localise all the data in one area on a disk and may be much quicker for reads.

Then again, I'm not sure if changing the size of a collection document (by many updates) may have a detrimental affect?  (i.e. low level would it have to move the document around on disk, or would it fragment the data anyway, since it may not preallocate enough space for it on storage on first insert)

**The question is**: Is one method recommended or significantly more highly performant than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to design a Mongo collection is to think of the way in which the data is most likely to be used and design it for that purpose. In your case your user will query favourites much more frequently that add them. Therefore the collection should be design to optimise this query.

With this in mind the first option is the most optimal of the two. However you might want to consider a slight modification to that structure.

As you have said the getFavourites method will be called for all users but will only return a list of favourites for 5% of users. This call will have to retrieve the favourites array and determine if it has content. While this does not cost too much you could pre-calculate this call by adding an additional field that is true only if the user has favourites. Therefore it will only be necessary to query this field and then only query for favourites if the value returned is true.

I imagine a structure as follows:

```
{
  _id : 123456,  (the user id),
  hasFavourites: 1,
  favourites : [
     { item_id : 43563, created_date : ... },
     { item_id : 31232, created_date : ... },
     { item_id : 23472, created_date : ... }
  ]
}
```

This document has favourites so the field hasFavourites is 1, if it didn't it would be 0.

Comment: I was assuming I would not even have an entry in the favourites collection if the user had no favourites.